# Why can't I craft anything with items from cheats?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I wanted to do some testing with the Nether so I made a fresh world on Survival, with cheats enabled. I used the following command to give myself 64 diamonds:

```
/give [me] 264 64 264
```

But for some reason I can't craft with them:

[image]

I tried this on a couple different worlds and I have the same problem. So I downloaded  a fresh Minecraft install from the website (1.4.2), and deleted the .minecraft folder so a new one would be generated. Created a brand new world, survival, with cheats enabled, same problem.

What am I doing wrong? Is it normal to not be able to craft with cheated items?

Comment: It's simpler and less error-prone to just use /gamemode to switch yourself Creative (mode 1), pick your resources, and switch back to Survival (mode 2).

Comment: Survival is mode 0

Comment: @Joe Right! I'm so used to seeing people mixing those up that now *I'm* remembering it wrong… Arg, dammit.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The command you have used is incorrect, the format for giving items is:

```
/give <player> <id> [amount] [data]
```

So as you can see, you've actually given yourself a stack of 64 diamonds with a data value of 264. The kind of diamonds needed to craft armour with has a value of 0, and so the recipe doesn't work.

The amount and data values are both optional (hence the square brackets), with the amount defaulting to 1 and the data defaulting to 0.

Comment: This is actually really cool. For adventure-type maps it allows you to give people usable items/rewards without them being able to cheat by crafting those items into something else.

Comment: @GrayStoat Yes but be careful -- an unused data value could become used in a future version and you'll find your items mutating!